# receive null as response from get_nodes_list proxmox php api

Tags: php, api, containers, virtual-machine, proxmox

im trying to use Proxmox's PHP Api to create new container but when i'm trying to send request to do so i receive this in error log of apache:

```
----------------------------------------------
FULL RESPONSE:\n\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nDate: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nServer: pve-api-daemon/3.0\r\nContent-Length: 197\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nExpires: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\n\r\n{"data":[{"maxdisk":1890533244928,"type":"node","id":"node/px2","disk":2463367168,"maxmem":8335933440,"uptime":270689,"cpu":0.0131703340463503,"maxcpu":4,"node":"px2","mem":4635709440,"level":""}]}\n\nEND FULL RESPONSE\n\nHeaders:\n\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nDate: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nServer: pve-api-daemon/3.0\r\nContent-Length: 197\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nExpires: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\n\nEnd Headers\n\nData:\n\n{"data":[{"maxdisk":1890533244928,"type":"node","id":"node/px2","disk":2463367168,"maxmem":8335933440,"uptime":270689,"cpu":0.0131703340463503,"maxcpu":4,"node":"px2","mem":4635709440,"level":""}]}\n\nEnd Data\n\nRESPONSE ARRAY:\n\narray (\n  'data' => \n  array (\n    0 => \n    array (\n      'maxdisk' => 1890533244928,\n      'type' => 'node',\n      'id' => 'node/px2',\n      'disk' => 2463367168,\n      'maxmem' => 8335933440,\n      'uptime' => 270689,\n      'cpu' => 0.013170334046350299,\n      'maxcpu' => 4,\n      'node' => 'px2',\n      'mem' => 4635709440,\n      'level' => '',\n    ),\n  ),\n)\n\nEND RESPONSE ARRAY\n----------------------------------------------
[:error] [pid 9148:tid 924] [client ::1:58574] ----------------------------------------------\nFULL RESPONSE:\n\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nDate: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nServer: pve-api-daemon/3.0\r\nContent-Length: 197\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nExpires: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\n\r\n{"data":[{"uptime":270689,"disk":2463367168,"maxmem":8335933440,"id":"node/px2","type":"node","maxdisk":1890533244928,"level":"","mem":4635709440,"node":"px2","maxcpu":4,"cpu":0.0131703340463503}]}\n\nEND FULL RESPONSE\n\nHeaders:\n\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nDate: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nServer: pve-api-daemon/3.0\r\nContent-Length: 197\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nExpires: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\n\nEnd Headers\n\nData:\n\n{"data":[{"uptime":270689,"disk":2463367168,"maxmem":8335933440,"id":"node/px2","type":"node","maxdisk":1890533244928,"level":"","mem":4635709440,"node":"px2","maxcpu":4,"cpu":0.0131703340463503}]}\n\nEnd Data\n\nRESPONSE ARRAY:\n\narray (\n  'data' => \n  array (\n    0 => \n    array (\n      'uptime' => 270689,\n      'disk' => 2463367168,\n      'maxmem' => 8335933440,\n      'id' => 'node/px2',\n      'type' => 'node',\n      'maxdisk' => 1890533244928,\n      'level' => '',\n      'mem' => 4635709440,\n      'node' => 'px2',\n      'maxcpu' => 4,\n      'cpu' => 0.013170334046350299,\n    ),\n  ),\n)\n\nEND RESPONSE ARRAY\n----------------------------------------------
[:error] [pid 9148:tid 924] [client ::1:58574] ----------------------------------------------\nFULL RESPONSE:\n\nHTTP/1.1 501 Method 'POST /nodes/px2/openvz' not implemented\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nConnection: close\r\nDate: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nServer: pve-api-daemon/3.0\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nExpires: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\n\r\n{"data":null}\n\nEND FULL RESPONSE\n\nHeaders:\n\nHTTP/1.1 501 Method 'POST /nodes/px2/openvz' not implemented\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nConnection: close\r\nDate: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nServer: pve-api-daemon/3.0\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nExpires: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 19:12:24 GMT\n\nEnd Headers\n\nData:\n\n{"data":null}\n\nEnd Data\n\nRESPONSE ARRAY:\n\narray (\n  'data' => NULL,\n)\n\nEND RESPONSE ARRAY\n----------------------------------------------
[:error] [pid 9148:tid 924] [client ::1:58574] This API Request Failed.\nHTTP Response - 501\nHTTP Error - HTTP/1.1 501 Method 'POST /nodes/px2/openvz' not implemented
```

I've only one Node called px2, when i call function to get nodes list as a response i get NULL. So i tried to put node name into path manually, but then received these errors in error.log

I'm using Proxmox v5.0-30, and as API i'm using this: https://github.com/CpuID/pve2-api-php-client

--- EDIT:
The Code used to create container:

```
<?php
require ('pve-1/pve2_api.class.php');

$pve2 = new PVE2_API("10.11.12.89", "root", "pam", "password");

$pve2->login();

if ($pve2->login()) {

    # Get first node name.
    $nodes = $pve2->get_node_list();
    $first_node = $nodes[0];
    unset($nodes);
    $vm 

    # Create a VZ container on the first node in the cluster.
    $new_container_settings = array();
    $new_container_settings['ostemplate'] = "local:vztmpl/ubuntu-16.04-standard_16.04-1_amd64.tar.gz";
    $new_container_settings['vmid'] = "7777";
    $new_container_settings['cpus'] = "2";
    $new_container_settings['description'] = "106(test-container)";
    $new_container_settings['disk'] = "8";
    $new_container_settings['hostname'] = "testapi.domain.tld";
    $new_container_settings['memory'] = "1024";
    $new_container_settings['nameserver'] = "10.11.12.233";

     print_r($new_container_settings);
    print("---------------------------\n");

    var_dump($pve2->post("/nodes/px2/openvz", $new_container_settings));
    print("\n\n");
} else {
    print("Login to Proxmox Host failed.\n");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: can you edit your post and add the request you issue ?

Comment: i've placed whole code which i used to create container.